# Netplan Error: Cannot bind to port 2893, Address is already in use

Tags: networking

I want to configure static IP address in Ubuntu.
Here you can see my configuration file for static IP addressing:

```
  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
   ethernets:
       wlp1s0:
          dhcp4: no
          addresses: [192.168.0.103/24]
          Gateway: 192.168.0.1
          Nameservers:
             Addresses: [127.0.0.53]
```

While testing the configuration through `$ sudo netplan try`, I get the following response:

**bind: Address already in use**

**netplan: fatal error: cannot bind to port 2983, is another daemon running?, exiting.**

Netstat shows the port in use by Netplan.

```
netstat -pnlt | grep ':2983'
```

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2983            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1524/netplan`

So can someone please give me a way to solve this issue??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got same problem today with one of my servers. The reason was because 2 packages exists for Ubuntu with same binary name: netplan and netplan.io. First is "Calendar Service" and the second is for networking. My server have netplan package installed. I just removed it and now netplan for networking works fine. May be it will helps to you.

Answer (score 1):

Same here ...

- installed debian server
- apt-get update
- apt-get upgrade
- reboot and it broke networking so I had to go on site and W%%#$ing fix it .. DIAF 'netplan'

apt-get remove --purge netplan* -y
apt-get install netplan.io -y